# How to enable multiple pods with same ports exposed on a k8s node?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration

i'm getting:
 `0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.`
while trying to run multiple jenkins slaves on the same k8s node.

each pod exposes a the same ports, this making it impossible to run 2 same pods on the same node.
i have  a service with a load balancer - but its not doing the trick.

is there a possibility to create a service that will generate random ports for each pod created?

Thanks!!!

edit: 
this is the service configured:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "jnlp",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/jnlp",
    "uid": "345230eb-5078-11e9-959a-1690183aeeb4",
    "resourceVersion": "90390",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-03-27T10:08:01Z",
    "annotations": {.....}
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "ssh",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 22,
        "targetPort": 22,
        "nodePort": 32417
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "app": "jnlp"
    },
    "clusterIP": "....",
    "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "sessionAffinity": "None",
    "externalTrafficPolicy": "Cluster"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {
      "ingress": [
        {
          "ip": "......"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

jenkins config:

```
podTemplate(label: slave, 
containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'mongodb',
            image: mongo_image,
            ttyEnabled: true,
            ports: [portMapping(name: 'mongo', containerPort: 27017, hostPort: 27017)],
    ),
    containerTemplate(name: 'elasticsearch',
            image: elastic_image,
            ttyEnabled: true,
            ports: [portMapping(name: 'elastic', containerPort: 9200, hostPort: 9200)],
    ),
    containerTemplate(name: 'jnlp',
            image: "******:${CONTAINER_TAG}",
            command: 'jenkins-slave',
            alwaysPullImage: true,
            privileged: true,
            label: 'jnlp', 
            envVars: [
                    envVar(key: 'HOME', value: "${JENKINS_HOME}"),
            ])
],
        imagePullSecrets: ['*******'],
        podRetention: always()
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that effectively make it multiple services, semantically? I guess what you're trying to do is not possible in the way you're currently attempting it.

Comment: Hi, Can you share your jenkins slave pods yaml ?  As each pod has different IP , you can have same port

Comment: The thing is - im deploying the slaves with a jenkins plugin - that doesnt let me set a service for each slave - so i set a service manually. 
ill upload it to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple pods use the same `nodePort` since this is a port on the actual machine that you will be binding to your pod. Since you are using a loadbalancer I don't see why you would need to use nodePorts. If you don't absolutely need to use nodePorts, simply remove it from your service.

Comment: when i try to remove nodePort and update , it automatically adds a new generated nodePort ... any thoughts?

Comment: The new nodePort is going to be different for each of the pods, so you don't have to worry about that. What yaml file are you using in the first place?

Comment: but it isnt different because i created a static service, so it has only 1 nodePort configured.
how can i make it dynamic ?

Comment: Can you post the yaml file you are using?

Comment: im using a jenkins plugin to deploy the pod, while the service was manually set(the yaml in the main post).

Comment: @MickeyKianovsky If your deployment uses replica set, then make sure you are only exposing the `containerPort`.

Comment: i added the jenkins config also.